# Save :Man window in session

Tags: buffers, sessions, manpages

## TL;DR: I want to persist `:Man` windows in sessions

---

I am [obsessed](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) with sessions, and use tpope's vim-obsession for managing them. Coupled with a scripted tmux, sessions make for a perfect "quit, go home, come back" workflow.

Recently, I decided to embark on learning perl. Perl wonderfully ships with a massive amount of documentation, all of which is accessible via `perldoc`. But, these pages are *also* available via manpages.

Perfect, says I: I can run vim, `:Man perl` to view the documentation, then `:term` to have a shell for experimenting with the scripts I'm writing as I write them.

I do this, then `:Obsession` to save the session, and quit and restart (`vim -S`) to see if it works the way I thought.

Unfortunately, the session didn't save my open `:Man` window: it's not even present in the `Session.vim` code.

---

I suspect this is a result of `:Man` setting `'buftype'=nofile`. I also suspect that what I am asking may be fundamentally impossible: I *could* edit the session code by hand, but there are so many cases and this is so error prone that even a one-time attempt to script this edit seems... unwieldy. By hand, I'm not even sure I'd know where to start, and it will just get overwritten by the next session save.

---

Obsession isn't really necessary to try this out yourself; all you need is `mksession`.

Comment: Yeah, you have a buffer with no swapfile associated, tied to a file that doesn't exist (e.g. `~/find.1~` for `man find`) and then a buffer type of `nofile` added for good measure. They couldn't have done much more to make that buffer as vapor to the session mechanism...short of waving their hands over it while chanting magic incantations..."you are not a real buffer....you do not exist".

Comment: BTW, that non-buffer gets loaded  with `:r !man ...` and I'm not sure if `:mks` would know how to deal with that even if it were an everyday, girl-next-door type of buffer. (I haven't tested that, though.)

Comment: @BLayer it’s a little more involved than `:r! man`, though only because we have to explicitly request `cat` as the manpager.

Comment: Explicitly request `cat` as the manpager? I thought that was just a system-specific workaround to the real goal of _unsetting_ manpager envvar...maybe I skimmed to quickly.  Anyways, I think my point stands independently from that part...the mks vs load-by-shell-command problem.

Comment: @BLayer If I unset MANPAGER, man fails. But yes your point stands